# Make Jenkins invisible to remote users

Tags: windows, jenkins, remote-access

I have a Jenkins server on my local Windows device, but I want to make it invisible to the outside world (office rules regarding servers). The obvious and unsubtle way, which works satisfactorily, is to set up a firewall rule to block incoming access to its port, but I feel there must be a Jenkins setting to stop it advertising its services to anyone but localhost. Can anyone tell me if there is?

Note that setting up user credentials is not a valid solution, as the server being visible but inaccessible without login still violates office rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Starting and Accessing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) you need `--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1` command line parameter:

> --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST - Binds Jenkins to the IP address represented by $HTTP_HOST. The default is 0.0.0.0 — i.e. listening on all available interfaces. 
>   For example, to only listen for requests from localhost, you could use: --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1

If you run your Jenkins as Windows service, you can extend command line arguments in `jenkins.xml` file in Jenkins home directory.

Similar [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/236405) (for Linux-oriented platforms) on ServerFault.

Comment: Thank you - that works as advertised. As a further note, in the Jenkins install directory there is a `jenkins.xml`, and within is a `<arguments>` tag where the `--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1` can be added, rather than playing about with RegEdit, etc. The ServerFault answer, however, is too Linux-oriented.

Comment: Sorry, i have missed that you were asking about Windows. Answer extended. Thank you.