# Make Jenkins login page private

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm just getting started with Jenkins: I installed it on my VPS, I linked it to a sub-domain I own (ci.example.com) and I can correctly log in and do whatever I need to do.

Question: I don't like the login page to be publicly accessible, how can I make it accessible only from specific IP addresses or hide it behind VPN?

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a duplicate of

[Make Jenkins invisible to remote users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779993/make-jenkins-invisible-to-remote-users/31780909#31780909)

... and there is an answer, too!

In short:

```
--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1
```

(e.g. in Debian, add it to /etc/default/jenkins )